# Is ther a better way of getting the file name and the last x diretory names by using pathlib

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I have the path `/bin/kk/bb/pp/hallo.png` and want to get: `pp/hallo.png`. I checked https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html  and found no direct way.

This is the way i use right now:

```
from pathlib import Path

a = Path("/bin/kk/bb/pp/hallo.png")

# get the parts i want 
b = list(a.parts[-2:])

# add / and join all together 
c = "".join([ "/" + x  for x in b])

d = Path(c)
d
```

Output:

```
PosixPath('/pp/hallo.png')
```

I'm not happy with this and searching for a better / cleaner way.

Maybe something like this:

```
a[-2:] -> PosixPath('/pp/hallo.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```py
from pathlib import Path

a = Path("/path/to/some/file.txt")

b = Path(*a.parts[-2:])
# PosixPath('some/file.txt')
```

Alternatively as a function:

```py
def last_n_parts(filepath: Path, n: int = 2) -> Path:
    return Path(*filepath.parts[-abs(n):])
```

---

The only reason I could think of that you'd need something like this is if you're specifying an output file that share the same directory structure. E.g. input is `/bin/kk/bb/pp/hallo.png` and output will be `/other/dir/pp/hallo.png`. In that case you can:

```py
in_file = Path("/bin/kk/bb/pp/hallo.png")
out_dir = Path("/other/dir")

out_file = out_dir / last_n_parts(in_file)
# PosixPath('/other/dir/pp/hallo.png')
```

Comment: This is good! I need it for a DataFrame, what I use as an index for my image data. I give my (train) script a path to the data and a sub-set of my DataFrame. The script and the image data is located on a cloud. So the root path to the data is not the same all the time.